# display an arrayList and a video at the same time

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist

i would like to display the arrayList of faces Rectangle and the video as a background at the same time. Here is my code that i was elaborated but I have not yet achieved the desired goal. This code allows to display the list of rectangles only and is fixed on the first image of the video (it does not display the video as a background). I don't know where the error comes from. can anyone help me please?

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DirectMediaPlayerComponentTest {

    private final int width = 720;
    private final int height = 480;
    private final JPanel panel;
    private final BufferedImage image;


    static ArrayList<FaceRectangle> recList;

    ArrayList<FaceRectangle> recToDisplay = new ArrayList<FaceRectangle>();



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String mrl = "dance_redacted1.mp4";

        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "lib");
        Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new DirectMediaPlayerComponentTest().start(mrl);
            }
        });
    }

    private DirectMediaPlayerComponentTest() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("vlcj Direct Media Player Component Test");


        panel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
                g2.setColor(Color.black);
                g2.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
                g2.drawImage(image, null, 0, 0);

             for ( FaceRectangle rec : recToDisplay ){ 
                  System.out.println(rec);     
                  g2.setColor(rec.getColor(rec.getId()));
                  g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                  g2.draw(new Rectangle2D.Double((rec.getTop())*1000, (rec.getLeft())*1000, (rec.getWidth())*1000, (rec.getHeight())*1000));

            }            
            }
        };
        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        panel.setOpaque(true);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        panel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        panel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        image = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration().createCompatibleImage(width, height);

        BufferFormatCallback bufferFormatCallback = new BufferFormatCallback() {
            public BufferFormat getBufferFormat(int sourceWidth, int sourceHeight) {
                return new RV32BufferFormat(width, height);
            }
        };

        mediaPlayerComponent = new DirectMediaPlayerComponent(bufferFormatCallback) {
            @Override
            protected RenderCallback onGetRenderCallback() {
                return new TestRenderCallbackAdapter();
            }
        };

        frame.setContentPane(panel);

        frame.setLocation(100, 100);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    //  Start playing a movie.

    private void start(String mrl) {
        // One line of vlcj code to play the media...
        mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia(mrl);
    }

    private class TestRenderCallbackAdapter extends RenderCallbackAdapter {

        private TestRenderCallbackAdapter() {
            super(new int[width * height]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDisplay(DirectMediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int[] rgbBuffer) {
            // Simply copy buffer to the image and repaint
            image.setRGB(0, 0, width, height, rgbBuffer, 0, width);
            panel.repaint();

            //for (ArrayList<FaceRectangle> rec : rectFace){
            for ( FaceRectangle rec : recList ){
                recToDisplay.clear();
                recToDisplay.add(rec);
                panel.repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(512);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add one thread for video and one for arrayList?

Comment: try to use a thread if you want several tasks to be executed at the same time

Comment: You can see this from documentation [Threads](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).